# Why two avatars of Lord Vishnu, Rama and Parasurama meet in the same timeline?

Tags: rama, parashurama

Lord parashurama came to fight with lord Rama when lord Rama broke the hara dhanu. Now, why these two avatars meet with each other? What was the main motivation of this occurrence? Does it mean that lord parashurama wanted to say/give something (his bow to defeat Ravana) to lord Rama?

Comment: because they're not the same type of avatars. Ram is purna avatar (Bhagavan/Paramatman/Vishnu = Ram). while Parashuram is avesha avatar (a jiva who has temporarily been given the powers of Bhagavan). Once his allotted time is over, Ram takes back Parashuram's powers. http://veda.wikidot.com/avatara

Answer (score 0):

While returning back to Ayodhya marrying Sita, Lord Rama encountered Parashurama.

> In that catastrophic darkness, that sand-muffled military of king
> Dasharatha has seen the son of Sage Jamadagni, namely Bhaargava Rama,
> the subjugator of kings of kings. He appeared calamitous in his look
> by wearing tufty matted and unruly head-hair, an unassailable one like
> Mt. Kailash, an unbearable one like the Epoch-End-Fire, irradiant with
> his own radiance, hence imperceivable for commoners, and such as he
> is, he clinched an axe on his right shoulder and clasped a bow in his
> left hand, that in simile is like a congeries of electroluminescence,
> and handling an arrow which is as if ready to electrocute, and he vied
> in his overall look with the devastator of triple cities, namely God
> Shiva. [1-74-16b, 17, 18, 19]

2. Parashurama challenged Lord Rama -

> Take an aim with an arrow that conquers enemy's citadels fixing it on
> this supramundane longbow... and oh, Kakutstha, should you be capable
> of it, thereafter I will give you a duel... [1-75-27]

3. Lord Rama accepted the challenge -

> Raghava, the nimble-handed vanquisher of his opponents, speaking thus
> in high dudgeon expropriated that estimable weapon, namely the longbow
> of Vishnu, from the hand of Bhaargava Rama, along with the long-arrow
> that is already fitted on it... [1-76-4]

4. Lord Rama successfully wielded the bow of Vishnu -

> On lifting up the bow that is already fitted with an arrow on
> bowstring, then Rama started to take aim with it, but being indecisive
> about the target, then Rama of Dasharatha irefully said this to Rama
> of Jamagadni. [1-76-5]

5. Parashurama recognise that Lord Rama is Vishnu -

> "I have realized your touch of nature as that of the Immutable Supreme
> Being, God of Gods, the Exterminator of the demon Madhu, namely
> Vishnu, by the touch of your handling that bow... oh, enemy-inflamer,
> blessedness alone betides you... [1-76-17]

6. Lord Rama destroyed the ascetic merits of Parashurama -

> But I triumphed over matchless realms of heavens with my ascesis, oh,
> Rama, you may hash them up with that irreversible arrow... let there
> be no time-lag... [1-76-16)

7. Parashurama leaves for Mahendra mountain -

> On seeing all of his realms of heavens are shot-blasted by Rama of
> Dasharatha, Rama of Jamadagni vanished in a trice to Mt. Mahendra, the
> heavenly mountain. [1-76-22]